# Error: expression cannot be used as a function?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I created a quick method in my program to compute the distance between two points using the distance formula, here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int distanceFormula(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    double d = sqrt((x1-x2)^2(y1-y2)^2);
    return d;
}
```

it gives me a compiler error on the line where I declare the `d` variable saying that

`error: expression cannot be used as a function`.

What does this mean? And what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11):

Be careful, `(x1-x2)^2` will not do an exponent of 2 here.
See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/.

Second, you probably forgot a `+` in your expression:

```
int distanceFormula(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
    double d = sqrt(pow(x1-x2, 2) + pow(y1-y2, 2));
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Ah! thank you! I was laying this out during math class and it totally slipped my mind about the power function, thank you so much

Comment: Just in case you are interested, `^` (XOR) is actually an operator in C/C++. See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/boolean/

Comment: Why not change the return type of the function to `double`?

Comment: @ForceBru Though I'm sure OP wasn't thinking about casting the returned result, I went with an answer that would respect his original method signature. But in many real life scenarios you might want to return `double` yes :)

Comment: Thanks @Mr_Pouet

Answer (score 3):

The compiler error is because `2(y1-y2)` is *invalid* syntax.

In this case `2` (or perhaps `(x1-x2)^2`) is the "expression" and `(y1-y2)` is taken as a function call argument list; this grammar production is simply not allowed.

Compare the following form where a binary operator (`*`) is introduced, which in turn makes the parser treat the subsequent `(y1-y2)` as an expression (bounded by grouping parenthesis) and not a function call. While it *won't do what is desired*, as `^` is not exponentiation and the resulting equation is nonsense, it should parse and compile.

```
sqrt((x1-x2)^2*(y1-y2)^2)
```